# How does a rollback work?

Tags: support

I have seen a badge Cleanup awared for the First Rollback. What does a rollback mean and how do we execute a rollback? Does it mean removing our question or answer?

Comment: Thanks, I have searched for the rollback but didn't get it. Thanks for the link.)

Comment: If you are looking for understanding of a specific feature, always helps to check the [meta-tag:faq] tag first.  The top voted question in that tag [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) is the complete index to the faq tag.